# Ruby conditional map and replace

Tags: ruby, arrays, text-manipulation

I'm trying to conditionally map an array I have:

Array that looks like [ "a", "b", "c" ]

I want to map it inline (using map!) to change anything that matches /b/ and change it to "bb". This doesn't seem to work though, it doesn't seem to be changing the array.

I want it to look like this [ "a", "bb", "c" ]

define the array:

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Try with a select chained to a map!, and it shows the changed value for the one element, and it didn't change the original array.

```
irb(main):002:0> a.select { |e| e =~ /b/ }.map! { |e| e = "bb" }
=> ["bb"]
irb(main):003:0> p a.inspect
"[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
```

So I tried doing the same thing, but assigning it to a new array, this only creates an array with any changed elements - not what I want

```
irb(main):004:0> cc = a.select { |e| e =~ /b/ }.map! { |e| e = "bb" } 
=> ["bb"]
irb(main):005:0> p cc.inspect
"[\"bb\"]"
=> nil
```

What am I missing here? I'm missing some Ruby fundamental knowledge here I think.

Comment: I find it annoying when people down vote a question without putting a comment explaining what the problem is. People would learn from the comment.

Answer (score 4):

You call `select` on `a`, which returns new instance of `Array`, on which in the next step you call `map!`, modifying this new instance (not the original one). To achieve what you want, you can do:

```
a.map! { |e| e =~ /b/ ? 'bb' : e }
```

Answer (score 3):

The correct logic looks like this:

```
results = a.map { |e| if e =~ /b/ then "bb" else e end }
```

The same logic using the ternary operator:

```
results = a.map { |e| e =~ /b/ ? "bb" : e }
```

If you really need to do the replace in-place then use `!` like this:

```
a.map! { |e| e =~ /b/ ? "bb" : e }
```

Here's why your code in your post isn't working the way you expect:

- Your `select` is returning a new array, then `map!` is modifying the new array. That's one issue.
- More important, the `select` method doesn't work the way you're using it. The `select` method returns *only* the items that match.

In general, don't use `!` for map unless you have a really good reason, and you understand it better, because Ruby `!` methods that modify objects in place tend to be a bit harder to debug and test reliably.

Comment: @awojo it's ternary operator.

Comment: If I knew a ton about ruby, I wouldn't have asked the question. Is stackoverflow not about learning and sharing knowledge? ...Thanks for the tip though, Marek Lipka.